# IndexOutOfRangeException exception with Cramer's Rule

Tags: arrays, vb.net, matrix, indexing

I am currently working on an assignement where I have to build a program who is able to solve with Cramer's rule. However, it seems like the two basic matrix that I need to build: matA and matB can't because of an index out of range and I really can't see where. Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim matA(2, 2) As Double
    Dim matB(2, 0) As Double
    Dim matC(2, 2) As Double
    Dim matResultat(0, 2) As Double
    Dim deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ, delta As Double

    Public Function det(ByVal A As Double(,)) As Double

        Dim determinant As Double

        determinant = 0

        For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
            If i = 1 Then
                determinant -= A(0, i) * (A(1, 0) * A(2, 2) - A(2, 0) * A(1, 2))
            ElseIf i = 0 Then
                determinant += A(0, i) * (A(1, 1) * A(2, 2) - A(2, 1) * A(1, 2))
            Else
                determinant += A(0, i) * (A(1, 0) * A(2, 1) - A(2, 0) * A(1, 1))
            End If
        Next

        Return determinant
    End Function

    Public Function solve(ByVal A As Double(,), ByVal B As Double(,)) As Double(,)

        Dim resultat(0, 2) As Double

        matC = A

        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To 2
                matC(j, i) = B(j, i)
            Next
            resultat(0, i) = det(matC)
            matC = A
        Next

        Return resultat
    End Function

    Private Sub ButtonSolve_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSolve.Click

        Try
            matA(0, 0) = TBX1.Text
            matA(0, 1) = TBY1.Text
            matA(0, 2) = TBZ1.Text
            matA(1, 0) = TBX2.Text
            matA(1, 1) = TBY2.Text
            matA(1, 2) = TBZ2.Text
            matA(2, 0) = TBX3.Text
            matA(2, 1) = TBY3.Text
            matA(2, 2) = TBZ3.Text

            matB(0, 0) = TBR1.Text
            matB(0, 1) = TBR2.Text
            matB(0, 2) = TBR3.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            MessageBox.Show("Vous devez remplir chaque case avec un nombre entier ou à virgule.")
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        matResultat = solve(matA, matB)

        deltaX = matResultat(0, 0)
        deltaY = matResultat(0, 1)
        deltaZ = matResultat(0, 2)
        delta = det(matA)

        If delta = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Le SEL admet une infinité ou aucune solution.")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Le SEL admet une solution unique." & vbCrLf & "X: " & deltaX / delta & vbCrLf & "Y: " & deltaY / delta & vbCrLf & "Z: " & deltaZ / delta)
        End If


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: you cant see where??? The line is crashes on is where - use the mouse to find out which one is indexed improperly

Comment: If `Dim matB(2, 0)` then it will crash for `matB(0, 1) = TBR2.Text`